# Sum over multiple indices

Tags: summation, code-request

I would like to be able to enter the following left hand side of an identity.  I can write the right hand side (i think) but am not sure about the left.  The Left hand side is

$$\sum_{i_1+i_2+...+i_n=k}\binom{k}{i_1,i_2,...,i_n}\frac{f(i_1)f(i_2)...f(i_n)}{k!}$$

where is a function that extracts coefficients from a previously defined generating function.  How do you implement this summation with a sum of multiple indicies equal to a particular $k$?

---

My particular $\,f$ are called Hypergeometric Bernoulli Numbers.  The code I have to generate the numbers is below:

```
 T[m_, x_] = Sum[x^j/j!, {j, 0, m}];
 g[m_, x_] = x^m/(m! (E^x - T[m - 1, x]));
```

The hypergeometric bernoulli numbers are extracted using the following

```
 b[m_, n_, M_] := b[m, n, M] = Coefficient[n! Normal[Series[g[m, x], {x, 0, M}]], x, n];
```

Now I want to sum over the $n$ term defined in the bernoulli number, so I basically want the $\,f$ I wrote in the formula to be replaced by `b[m,i[j],M]`.

Comment: I have merged your follow-up question with this one; and have also incorporated changes suggested by @BobHanlon .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what Eleven-eleven is asking, but I think I can write a function that gives his type-set expression (requiring two input variables `n` and `k`).

The first step is to do the math problem.  How do you write the sum in a computer-friendly way? Like this:
$$\sum_{i_1+i_2+\ldots +i_n = k} = \sum_{i_1=0}^k \sum_{i_2=0}^{k-i_1} \cdots\sum_{i_{n-1}=0}^{k-i_1-i_2\ldots-i_{n-2}}\,,$$
and $i_n = k - i_1 - i_2 -\ldots i_{n-1}$ is fixed.

Now proceed with the sum.

```
elevenEleven[n_, k_, m_, M_] := 
  Module[{i},
    With[{sumIt = 
      Sequence @@ Table[{i[a], 0, k - Sum[i[b], {b, 1, a - 1}]}, {a, 1, n - 1}]},
      i[n] = k - Sum[i[e], {e, 1, n - 1}];
      Sum[Multinomial @@ Table[i[c], {c, 1, n}] * Product[b[m,i[d],M], {d, 1, n}]/k!, 
      sumIt]
    ]
  ]
```

Here `sumIt`will basically generate the iterators for the multi-dimensional `Sum` in the main body.  The statement `i[n] = k - Sum[i[e], {e, 1, n - 1}]` appearing in the main body enforces $i_n = k - i_1 - i_2 -\ldots i_{n-1}$.

Let's test it for $n=4$, $k=2$, $m=4$ and $M=5$:

```
elevenEleven[3, 2, 4, 5]
```

> 7/50

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that belasarius is what I need.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I finished my answer.  Please check if the result is correct.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I fixed a typo in my answer: `1/n!` to `1/k!`.

Comment: I have replaced with what I needed and It seems that my sum is always 0

Comment: yes, I can't get a result that is different from 0

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I don't understand what you mean by "I have replaced with what I needed and It seems that my sum is always 0".  Exactly *what* did you replace??

Comment: I replaced f with my function.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I think you should as a new question, and include your code for f, and one of our (belisarius or my) codes for generating that sum.

Comment: That is what I am going to do.  I'm on my way to work so it won't be until later tonight, but I'll include everything from top to bottom.  Thanks a bunch.  i appreciate your help.

Comment: I resubmitted a new question.  Can you take a look at it?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I have edited my answer: please review.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting problem. Following is cleaner IMO, and quite a bit faster on larger cases than accepted ans. (e.g. over 1000X faster on `{n, k, m, M} = {7, 20, 5, 6}`, ~5000X faster on `{n, k, m, M} = {8, 21, 6, 7}`) :

```
Module[{f, jp, n = #1, k = #2, m = #3, M = #4}, 
   jp = IntegerPartitions[k, {n}, Range[0, k]];
   f[x_] := f[x] = b[m, x, M];
   Tr[Multinomial @@@ (Tally /@ jp)[[All, All, 2]]*Multinomial @@@ jp*
      Times @@@ Map[f, jp, {2}]]/(k!)] &[n, k, m, M]
```

Comment: Nicely done! Alternatively, one could have used `FrobeniusSolve[]` to generate the indices…

Comment: @J. M.: Thanks, coming from you means extra. I find using `IntegerPartitions` with specified domain faster than `FrobeniusSolve` for these kind of weak composition problems, In any case, had the "DOH!" moment at dinner, see update that is *vastly* more efficient...

Comment: I see what you mean; not using `Permutations[]` helps quite a bit. :)

Answer (score 2):

If the indices run from zero:

```
n = 4; k = 3;
idxs = Join @@ (Permutations /@ (PadRight[#, n] & /@  IntegerPartitions[k]));
Sum[whatever[i], {i, idxs}]
whatever[s_List] := ( Multinomial @@ s) Times @@ ( f /@ s) / k!

(*

 4 f[0] f[1]^3 + 6 f[0]^2 f[1] f[2] + 2/3 f[0]^3 f[3]

*)
```

If you want to sum up k from 0 to n:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
n = 4;
idxs[n_, k_] := Join @@ (Permutations /@ (PadRight[#, n] & /@ IntegerPartitions[k]));
whatever[s_List, k_] := ( Multinomial @@ s) Times @@ ( f /@ s)/k!
Sum[whatever[i, k], {k, 0, n}, {i, idxs[n, k]}]

(*

f[0]^4 + 4 f[0]^3 f[1] + 6 f[0]^2 f[1]^2 + 4 f[0] f[1]^3 + f[1]^4 + 
 2 f[0]^3 f[2] + 6 f[0]^2 f[1] f[2] + 6 f[0] f[1]^2 f[2] + 
 3/2 f[0]^2 f[2]^2 + 2/3 f[0]^3 f[3] + 2 f[0]^2 f[1] f[3] + 
 1/6 f[0]^3 f[4]
*)
```

Comment: The indices would run from 0.  But i'm a little confused about how to implement this with the multinomial coefficient and the function f...

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Give me a few minutes

Comment: Okay thanks @belisarius!

Comment: @belisarius is there not a $1/k!$ missing?

Comment: @QuantumDot yup, editing, thanks

Comment: This goes faster than my answer... any ideas why?

Comment: @QuantumDot Not sure, but may be because of the ReplaceAll

Comment: I want to write this as a function of $n$ and $k$ as opposed to just a sum for predetermined numbers like $n=4$.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Just define `sum[n_, k_] := Sum[whatever[i, k], {i, idxs[n, k]}]`and keep the definitions of my last snippet

Comment: why is there a 2/3 in front of f[0]^3 f[3]?  Shouldn't this be 4?

Comment: My f is a function which extracts coefficients from a previously defined polynomial.  When I substitute it for f, I'm not sure it is being read properly.  What should I do?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I don't think either of us (belisarius or I) understand what you mean.  Please ask a new question (and include what modifications/additions you made to our codes)

Comment: okay.  I will do this later this evening when I am home from work.

Comment: @QuantumDot Certainly not.

Comment: I wrote a new question.  Can you take a look at it?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Nope. You haven't told me what's wrong with this answer yet.

Comment: I never said you were wrong.  I  having trouble implementing my function with the "f" in your answer.  This is what my new question is about.