# Sum Over Multiple Indices part 2

Tags: summation, code-request

Recently I asked [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69496/sum-over-multiple-indices) as I was trying to see how to write a particular Identity.  I asked about how to write the following sum:

$$\sum_{i_1+i_2+...+i_n=k}\binom{k}{i_1,i_2,...,i_n}\frac{f(i_1)f(i_2)...f(i_n)}{k!}$$

It is my "f" that is the topic of this question.   My particular "f" are called Hypergeometric Bernoulli Numbers.  The code I have to generate the numbers is below:

```
 g[m_, x] := x^m/(m! (E^x - T[m - 1, x]))
```

where

```
 T[m_, x_] := Sum[x^j/j!, {j, 0, m}]
```

The hypergeometric bernoulli numbers are extracted using the following

```
 b[m, n, M] = b[m_, n_, M_] := Coefficient[ n! Normal[Series[g[m, x], {x, 0, M}]], x, n]
```

Now I want to sum over the $n$ term defined in the bernoulli number, so I basically want the "f" I wrote in the formula to be replaced by "b[m,n,M]".  I had two helpers submit sequences on the linked page but the way I am implementing them seems incorrect.  I was hoping to have someone help me integrate the "b" into the expression for the "f".  Thank you.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: The $f$ in your equation above appears to take one argument.  The `b[m,n,M]` which is supposed to replace $f$ takes three arguments.  Can you clarify the relationship between `b` and $f$?

Comment: Sure.  f was just a dummy function in the example that I gave earlier.  I can choose any m and M I want and it shouldn't affect the identity's structure.  For b, I am looking for the expression to have b[m,i[j],M] instead of f(i[j]).

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment.

Use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` to define `T` and `g` in closed-form.

```
T[m_, x_] = Sum[x^j/j!, {j, 0, m}]
```

> (E^x*Gamma[1 + m, x])/m!

To demonstrate the increased efficiency of the closed-form (i.e., use of `Set` compared to `SetDelayed`)

```
T2[m_, x_] := Sum[x^j/j!, {j, 0, m}];

(T2[10, 2.3] // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]/
    (T[10, 2.3] // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]
```

> 1.2

```
(T2[100, 2.3] // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]/
    (T[100, 2.3] // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]
```

> 5.8

In your definition of `g` you left out a `Blank` in the LHS

```
g[m_, x_] = x^m/(m! (E^x - T[m - 1, x])) // FullSimplify
```

> x^m/(E^x*(Gamma[1 + m] - 
>            m*Gamma[m, x]))

In your definition of `b` you have the memorization reversed (see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)

```
b[m_, n_, M_] := 
 b[m, n, M] = Coefficient[n! Normal[Series[g[m, x], {x, 0, M}]], x, n]
```

Comment: Thank you for you input.  What is the advantage of defining the above functions your way? (novice mathematica user)

Comment: Efficiency. As originally shown, `Set` provides a closed-form rather than keeping the definition of the function as a `Sum`. Added timing comparisons for different definitions of `T`. You can experiment with different definitions for `g`.